# react implict return in an onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So I have been seeing this in the codebase recently. An implicit return from an `onClick`

```
<Button onClick={() => history.push('/urlTing') }>
   Ting
</Button>
```

Is this a big no-no? Or is it better? Any input here would be appreciated. Both appear to provide the desired behavior.

Obviously here is what it looks like without the implicit return.

```
<Button onClick={() => {
   history.push('/urlTing'); 
}}>
   Ting
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make a difference. If you don't want the implicit return while keeping the one-line format, use the [`void` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void#non-leaking_arrow_functions):

```
<Button onClick={() => void history.push('/urlTing') }>
   Ting
</Button>
```

Comment: is this true???

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void#non-leaking_arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the implicit return. The `onClick` event handler's return value does not get used by react. Per the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

> Another difference is that you cannot return `false` to prevent default behavior in React. You must call `preventDefault` explicitly.

Therefore, it does not matter what your handler returns, or if it returns anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a callback on each render inside markup, in itself is not the best practice. Back to the question: the main difference, as you mentioned, is between the return value. I doubt the `onClick` API from React will ever change. But if in the future there will be some kind of a return value expected - that's where you may get yourself into some troubles if you DO return something.

The rule of thumb: if you are not asked to return something - don't do that.

Comment: I appreciate that you pointed out it's not a good idea to inline this in the render.